# Is the age of an object in Google Cloud Storage affected by calls to set meta?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to use Google Cloud Storage's lifecycle management features on a bucket, but I want to circumvent it for certain files (basically auto delete all files after 1 day, except for specific files that I want to keep). If I call the [set metadata API endpoint](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/storage/0.8.0/storage/file?method=setMetadata) will that update the age of the object and prevent the delete from occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set metadata changes the last updated time, not the creation time.  TTL is keyed off of creation time, so that will not prevent TTL cleanup.

However, you could do a copy operation, and just set the destination to be the same as the source.  That would update the creation time, and would be a fast operation as it can copy in the cloud.

That being said, it would probably be safer to just  use a different bucket for these files.  If your job to keep touching the files goes down they may get deleted.